# Updating column type in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to update the type of a column in an Oracle table from varchar2(50) to varchar2(200).

I 've started doing some impact analysis that this change might have with searching in which packages this field is used, but after looking at few it seems that the field length is not specified anywhere. The only thing that is specified is the column type which at this case is **varchar2**.

My question is:

When the only thing that you want to change is the field length of a varchar2 type of one specific column, does this impact any underlying packages that this field might be referenced from?

Thanks

Comment: I believe, you might need to come back after your impact analysis and integration testing based on the answers, to mark one of the answer as answered ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You just need to make sure that wherever the `column` is being referred in the `TYPE` declaration, you have mentioned as `column%type` and not hardcoded as `VARCHAR(50)`.
2. See if there are any `type` is explicitly created as `database object` referring this column, if it is hardcoded with the size, then it would fail there too.

Do this impact analysis first, especially if your `application/system` is quite old or legacy. Developers at that time might not have thought about the future and might have hardcoded the size as I described above. I have seen it happening in one of the application I worked on, and fortunately caught it during `system integration testing`. So, do the `impact analysis` thoroughly and do the `integration testing` as good as possible.

Answer (score 1):

> When the only thing that you want to change is the field length of a varchar2 type of one specific column, does this impact any underlying packages that this field might be referenced from

This is exactly the scenario that the [`%Type` type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/type_attribute.htm) attempts to solve, viz that if you change the underlying type on the referenced column, that dependent artifacts (like packages) referencing the column will remain in synch.

So unfortunately, if you have defined parameters and variables in your packages as `varchar2(50)`, you will need to manually update these to the new width, in which case you can change it to `MYTABLE.MYCOLUMN%TYPE` to protect against a future change.

Answer (score 1):

What, exactly, do you mean by "the only thing that is specified is the column type"?

If you mean that your code always uses anchored types, i.e.

```
l_variable_name table_name.column_name%type;
```

then whenever you change the data type in the underlying code, the changes will automatically be propagated through your code.  That's one of the major benefits of using anchored types-- it prevents type declarations in your code from getting out of sync with the declarations of columns in the table.

Comment: By saying : "the only thing that is specified is the column type"

See example:
v_sp_columns(7).column_name := 'PAYEE_NAME';
v_sp_columns(7).datatype := 'VARCHAR2';

No length specified in this package

Comment: @Andreas - How does that declare a variable?  Is the `v_sp_columns` collection consumed by some other piece of code that is generating dynamic SQL for every query you run against the table?  That would be a rather insane architecture.